# Use all JAR files in lib/ as dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I like to drop all JAR file dependencies that are not in Maven Central, into a `lib/` directory in the root of my Java projects.

Is there a way to make Gradle automatically add all JAR files in `lib/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. Simply add the following lines to your `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Answering my own question right away may seem weird, but I tend to forget how this works and I want to find it on SO next time I need it.

Comment: I'll do that, but I have to wait for 2 more days before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: hm, nice and compact. I guess I'll have to start looking at Gradle to see if I like it more than Maven.

Comment: @Gimby totally agree. Build files are always nice to read, but sometimes it's hard to figure out how something works if you don't know Groovy.